# What should be the size of input and hidden state in GRUCell of tensorflow (python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am new to tensorflow (1 day of experience).

I am trying following small code to create a simple GRU based RNN with single layer and hidden size of 100 as follows:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# parameters
batch_size = 50
hidden_size = 100

# create network graph
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])
output_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_size)

initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

hidden_state = initial_state

output_of_cell, hidden_state = cell(input_data, hidden_state)
```

But I am getting following error for last line (i.e. call to `cell()`)

```
Linear is expecting 2D arguments: [[50], [50, 100]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input to the `GRUCell`'s call operator are expected to be 2-D tensors with `tf.float32` type. The following ought to work :

```
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_size)

initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

hidden_state = initial_state

output_of_cell, hidden_state = cell(input_data, hidden_state)
```

Comment: Actually using `input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 1])` worked. I then had to reshape my input data from an array of length `50` to a `50X1` matrix.

Comment: Edited to account for `input_size`. Yes, in general, your input vector can be of arbitrary size.

Comment: Thanks! I think you will be able to help me further. Could you please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233056/how-can-i-complete-following-gru-based-rnn-written-in-tensorflow